# How to implement Coroutines on iOS

Tags: ios, arm, coroutine

I am porting a C++ project to iOS for use on iPhone and iPad.  This project uses the Boost.Coroutine library extensively.  Boost.Coroutine does not have an implementation for the iPhone's ARMv6/ARMv7 instruction set.

- Are there other coroutine libraries that can run on iOS?
- If not, is it possible to write coroutine behavior on ARM?  I can see a few potential ways to do this:

  - Write assembly instructions directly to perform the stack manipulation.  I am not very well versed in assembly, and I'm worried that the ARM architecture may not include the instructions necessary to copy & paste the stack, or to manually move the stack pointer.
  - Write coroutines using something similar to pthreads, or Win32 fibers.  I'm not sure if there's something like this that could be used on iOS.
  - Implement coroutines, perhaps even Boost.Coroutine itself, on top of threads.  This seems the most likely to work, but would definitely have performance drawbacks.

Note: Unity supports coroutines in C# on iOS; I'm not sure if this is limited to a smaller subset of typical coroutine behavior.  If not, does this mean Unity has a solution?

Comment: Can you say anything about the specific pattern that you want coroutines for? It would be helpful, above and beyond a bare answer, to be able to say something like 'the reason it's difficult to do Y is that the normal pattern is X'.

Comment: Coroutines are generally a bad idea -- poor man's multitasking.  And you can accomplish most of the same functionality using iOS dispatch queues.  (Keep in mind that it's very dangerous to muck with the call stack.)

Comment: @Hot Licks Coroutines are useful enough to want them (or more powerful feature like continuations) in a language, and they are not a poor man's multitasking. Take a single-thread producer/consumer - it can be expressed naturally with coroutines, multithreaded version of the same will require locks. State machines are other common example. If coroutines are bad idea why many modern languages have a built-in support for them? Why people implement them for languages without such support (from C to C#)? Dispatch queues are nice but irrelevant here.

Comment: Some languages, such as those that implement "continuations" need something similar to coroutines, but most languages do not.  As to producer/consumer, let me assure you that, on a modern operating system, the coroutine version will be much more complex than the multithreaded version (and will almost certainly require locks to prevent destructive interference from the OS).  I once started out to implement a coroutine scheme on a bare PALM IV micro, but ended up discovering that a non-preemptive tasking scheme was cleaner.  This was a classical producer/consumer tape copy utility for IBM 5100.

Comment: @Hot Licks My main point is that many cases are better expressed with coroutines (when they are present). Even if multithreaded implementation is more effective (looks like you know better about this) coroutines are still semantically different feature - in most cases one should think about readability first and performance later.

Comment: @hoha - Coroutines, at a semantic level, are indeed a "different beast", and not really one that's logical to get your head around -- the concept of returning from a call with a call is simply mind-boggling.  Continuations and the like do not use coroutines in their "pure" form (and continuations are hard enough to conceptualize).

Comment: @hoha -- And I'm not (specifically) talking about performance here, but rather conceptual clarity and the reliability and robustness of both the implementation and the concepts underlying it.  Coroutines simply have too many "surprises" waiting if you wander even slightly off the given path.

Comment: @Hot Licks Yes, continuations do not use coroutines, it's other way around - coroutines are trivially implemented with a first-class continuations. As for mind-boggling - some find recursion or pointers mind-boggling but still people have them in their programs. It's a matter of study. Same for coroutines - they are being introduced in new versions of many popular languages (like Perl or Ruby) - this speaks for itself I think.

Comment: @Tommy Coroutines are primarily used in this project for the RPC library.  In the interest of pulling ongoing fixes and improvements from the original project, I'd like to keep my solution as similar as possible to the source implementation.  i.e. if I must rewrite their RPC library to not use coroutines I will, but I'd like to exhaustively investigate the options for implementing coroutines on iOS first.

Comment: @Hot Licks As to the discussion over whether coroutines should be used in general - even the original authors of my project agree that coroutines ultimately proved to be a poor solution for their problem (I think primarily due to code complexity and poor performance).  But writing coroutines out of the project just isn't an option right now for them.

Comment: Continuing to flail an expired equine, it should be remembered that coroutines were invented before "automatic storage" was the de-facto standard.  There was no call stack to swap.  Coroutines and stack-based automatic storage do not coexist very well.

Comment: @HotLicks What will you recommend to implement actor model - lightweight many concurrent execution context?

Comment: @Eonil - In general, a work queue model is the best way to handle multiple "units of work" in a concurrent environment.

Comment: @HotLicks Do you mean that work-queue model can represent execution-context better than actor model? Or am I misunderstanding what the execution-context is?

Comment: @Eonil - The "actor model" is a theoretical model that could never be realized, in pure form, in "real life".  The work queue scheme is a practical implementation of the actor model.

Answer (score 5):

You almost certainly don't want to write assembly instructions to perform the stack manipulation. iOS is already on its third version of the ARM instruction set, having transitioned from ARMv6 through ARMv7 to ARMv7s. As of the iPhone 5, Apple has further added the artificial barrier that you may not submit an application with an ARMv6 fork that also supports the full iPhone 5 screen. I'm sure Apple's motivation is to ensure it can transition to processors without an ARMv6 compatibility mode at some point in the future but for us developers it obviously means not becoming too dependent on the specific instruction set.

That leaves threads. iOS has a full set of well-developed threading mechanisms and pthread is there to expose the relevant subset. Grand Central Dispatch tends to be the normal solution used now to ensure that different tasks can occur simultaneously so swallows most of the Internet documentation but the lower-level solutions remain.

Obvious trivial example, using an [NSConditionLock](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSConditionLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (void)methodOnThread1
{
    while(1)
    {
        [conditionLock lockWhenCondition:kMoreInputAvailable];

        // process whatever is currently in the common access pool

        [conditionLock unlockWithCondition:kWaitingForInput];
    }
}

- (void)methodOnThread2
{
    while(1)
    {
         // do whatever is necessary to produce more input,
         // creating it locally and taking as long as it takes


        [conditionLock lockWhenCondition:kWaitingForInput];

        // push input to common access pool, by whatever means

        [conditionLock unlockWithCondition:kMoreInputAvailable];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

boost.coroutine (from Oliver Kowalke; reviewed from boost community last month) uses boost.context which supports ARMv6 (ARM Cortext Ax)